# Time based versus milage based service

Tags: maintenance, hyundai, scheduled-maintenance, service, servicing

My car's maintenance schedule says I need to service every 7,500 miles or 6 months. It is now 6 months but my cars has only 4500 miles. Do I still need to get it serviced?

Should I follow the service schedule of 6 months or the 7,500 miles?

If I follow miles I probably won't need to service until around 10 months. Will this void the warranty on the car or will it not get affected?

Answer (score 2):

The guidelines are "which ever comes first." So in your case, you'd need to do it at 6-months, not at 7,500 miles. Yes, if you do not follow these instructions, you do run the chance of voiding your warranty, but that really depends on the manufacturer and what they will allow. Some are a little easier than others, but they give you a maintanence schedule for a reason. Believe me when I say, if you don't follow it, it is a prime way for them to legally say, "Sorry, not our problem because you didn't complete the maintanence as scheduled." If they don't have to pay for something, they will find a way. And since you didn't do the maintanence correctly, they will use that against you.

As for a reason for actually changing the oil on time before the mileage comes about is that the additive packages in oil will break down over time, just as they will breakdown with mileage. You want to keep the level of protection your engine (or other mechanical parts) need. You can never go wrong with the routine maintanence.

Comment: What I find odd,is the in the UK, it is often now "2 years or XXK miles" but cars in the USA skill need a service ever 6 months.